# A python class contains an instance of another class, which object will be called first

Tags: python

My sample code is below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.age)

class Bar:
    obj_foo = Foo()
    print obj_foo 
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

obj_bar = Bar("Sam")  
print obj_bar
```

I want to know the execution flow. Can anyone help me to understand?

Comment: Put the `print` debugs in the `__init__` fns

Answer (score 4):

## Old school debugging

```
print(0)
class Foo:
    print(1)
    def __init__(self):
        print(2)
        self.age = 'Age'

    def __str__(self):
        print(3)
        return str(self.age)

class Bar:
    print(4)
    obj_foo = Foo()
    print(obj_foo)
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(5)
        self.name = name

    def __str__(self):
        print(6)
        return str(self.name)

print(7)
obj_bar = Bar("Sam")
print(obj_bar)
print(8)
```

My FORTRAN teacher would be proud!

It outputs:

```
0
1
4
2
3
Age
7
5
6
Sam
8
```

So here's the order:

- Start of the script
- class Foo is defined
- class Bar is defined
- one Foo is instantiated
- the Foo is printed
- Foo's Age is printed
- Script continues
- one Bar is instantiated
- the Bar is printed
- Bar's Name is printed
- Script finishes

## Spyder + pdb

For more complex scripts, it might be a good idea to use specialized tools. For example [spyder](https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/) with [pdb](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html).

If you installed Python with [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python), you don't need to install anything else.

Run your script with Debug > Debug (Ctrl + F5), press Ctrl + F10 multiple times to see the execution, press Ctrl + F11 if you want to step into a function or method.